# Spring MVC : How to post related entity objects and save in DB?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new to Spring/Java EE and I'm trying out some tutorials.
I have two entity classes, User and UserType. 
I want to create and save a user. UserType is a drop-down in the creation form.
Can you tell me how to save the UserType during the user creation?

1. Should I pass it as a UserType object?
2. Should I just pass the UserType's id (Integer)?

(Just showing below code as an example, it's not complete)
As you can see below, user has a property called UserType

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne
    private UserType type;//one to one
}
public class UserType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}

//HTML code for the UserType dropdown
<select th:field="*{type}">
<option th:each="type : ${types}" th:text="${type.name}" th:value="${type.id}"></option>
</select>

//Controller save user code
user.setType(new UserType(Integer.parseInt(type), ""));
this.userRepo.save(user);
```

When I try to run this I'm getting "Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'UserType' for property 'type' error.

What is the best way to save entities with relationships like above? Please share if you have any resources to learn this.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should pass userType's  `id` then in `service` or `controller` find the userType by `id` and set it for `user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass userType's `id` then in `service` or `controller` find the userType by `id` and set it for `user`.

```
UserType userType = userTypeRepo.find(Integer.parseInt(type));
//check userType!= null
user.setType(userType);
this.userRepo.save(user);
```

Answer (score 2):

in controller field type comes with type.id . you should convert in into real type class (entity or dto),  best practices - it's use DTO.
you can convert type.id into real type object by mane ways.

1. **simple case** (you use it one or two times):

   //in controller

   UserType userType = dao.getByTypeId(typeId); // get object from db by id.
   user.setType(userType);
2. better variant create **converter**  [spring Coverter  documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert) (you can use this converter not only once , it's applyed for all controllers . Once created converter , applyed in many places). Converter get type.id and return userType by type.id

   @Component
   public final class UserTypeConverter implements Converter {
       private Long userTypeId;
       private UserTypeDao userTypeDao;

   ```
   public LocalDateTimeConverter(Long userTypeId) {
       this.userTypeId= userTypeId;
   }

   @Override
   public UserType  convert(Long userTypeId) {
       if (userTypeId== null) {
           return null;
       }

       return userTypeDao.findById(userTypeId);
   }
   ```

   }
3. **PropertyEditor** [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration)same idea as for Converter , but uses for a bit different case : when you work with UserType as String text. see

good example [Spring From the Trenches: Using Type Converters With Spring MVC](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-using-type-converters-with-spring-mvc/)

simple example 
[Spring MVC - Binding Java Backing Objects with Custom Converters](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-mvc-custom-converter/)